# How to convert varchar contents(1,2,3) data to integer array in SQL without using Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables called `tblfilms` and `tblfilmdetails`.

First table **`tblfilm`** columns and data.

```
categoryID  filmCodes
----------  ----------
1           1,2,3
2           4,5,6
```

Second table **`tblfilmdetails`** columns and data.

```
filmCode  filmName
--------  ----------
1         Kungfu Panda
2         Inside out
3         Karate Kid
4         Terminator
5         Jumanji
6         Batman
```

I need to get `filmName` from `tblfilmdetails` table where `categoryID` equals 1.

I have tried the below query to achieve it but it shows error

```
select filmname from tblfilmdetails where filmCode in (select filmCodes from tblfilm where categoryID=1)
```

The problem is because my `filmCodes` column is `varchar` data so that it returns error that it cannot be convert a `varchar` to `int`.

How do I achieve this?

**I do not want to use Stored Procedure due to some other reason.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these types of cases you can leverage the string matching in SQL like below query

```
select * from tblfilms f inner join tblfilmdetails d on 
','+f.filmcodes like '%,'+cast(d.filmcode as varchar)+',%'
```

**Explanation:**
We add a comma to the string of feecodes while matching so that each filmcode in string starts and ends with comma and match it so on the left side with

```
'%,'+cast(d.filmcode as varchar)+',%'
```

which translates to filmcode with comma at start and end anywhere in the string

**[Working sql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cf3c/6)**

Comment: Thank you for your blessings :)

Comment: This is not proper solution when you go with Query optimization

Answer (score 4):

First you need to have Split function and the use below Simple query

**Split Function**

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))  
    RETURNS @Results TABLE (ITEM nvarchar(4000))  
AS  
BEGIN  
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, 
      @EndIndex INT
      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@String, LEN(@String) - 1, LEN(@String)) <> @Delimiter
      BEGIN
            SET @String = @String + @Delimiter
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)

            INSERT INTO @Results(ITEM)
            SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)))

            SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@String))
      END
    RETURN  
END
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM tblfilms AS M
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(M.filmCodes,',') AS T
    INNER JOIN tblfilmdetails AS G ON G.filmCode = CAST(T.ITEM AS int)
WHERE M.categoryID = 1
```

Comment: There are far more optimal splitters than user defined function with loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert filmCode from int to varchar by using "CAST".
In your example:
   select filmname from tblfilmdetails where cast(filmCode as varchar) in (select filmCodes from tblfilm where categoryID=1)
Hope it work.

Comment: Tried this. No errors but returns nothing but column header.

Answer (score -1):

You need to split filmcodes into seperate row.

Try this.

```
declare @tb as Table (CategoryId int, FilmCodes nvarchar(50))
declare @ProcessdeTb as Table (CategoryId int, FilmCodes nvarchar(50))
insert into @tb select 1,'1,2,3'
union select 2,'4,5,6'

insert into @ProcessdeTb
SELECT CategoryId,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS FilmCodes
FROM
(
SELECT CategoryId,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(FilmCodes,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   @tb
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)


select * from @ProcessdeTb

select filmname from tblfilmdetails where filmCode in (select filmCodes from @ProcessdeTb where categoryID=1)
```